# Garner's Formula to find a and b given 2 mod equations equal the same variable

Tags: rsa

I'm working on a Chinese Remainder Theorem Garner's Formula problem in my Cryptography module and was hoping for some help.

---

Question:
Given the data below use Garner’s formula to find T,U and s

$$ N = pq = 6815731 $$
$$ s \% p = 1 $$
$$ s \% q = 62537 $$

$ s = a \% p $

$ s = b \% q $

$ T = p-1 mod q $

$ U = (b-a)T mod q $

$ s = a+Up $

*(p = the smaller prime)*

I've figured out $p = 13, q = 524287 $, and $ T = 362968$ and have tried using modular inverses and [this](https://github.com/marcellomaugeri/Garner-Algorithm-Python) python program to figure out *a* and *b* with no avail.
There seems to be little information or examples on Garner's Theorem online.
I'm stumped on how to find *a* and *b* and would appreciate any help

Comment: It is better to write this solution as an answer and close accept your answer.

Comment: No solution for it yet, am hoping on some help to solve it